# creating buttons from db xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, button, .net-4.0

i have a db which contains 2 tables, one of them descibes credit cards and holds their number, owner and an id; the other one describes the monthly charges of the card, holding their amount dates and the id of the card(wich is the foreign key to the first table).

in my program i am creating a main menu which will allow the user to chose the card, and than it will open a new window that will show the card's charges.  in the main menu i would like to create a button for every credit card, and design it as a cover flow.

i am using wpf, and i am new at this.  the way i am creating it is through the code behind, i am querying the db for the card's numbers and foreach result i am creating a button.
i want to know if this is the right way to do it, or is there any other way to create the buttons through the xaml?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called Data Templates, you create a template that represents a single item, and then apply the template to the menu control and set it's `ItemsSource` property to the rows from your database.

Here's a quick post I found that might help: http://www.vbknowledgebase.com/?Id=133&Desc=WPF-Menu-Databinding

I'm sure you can find more with a quick web search.

Comment: i created a data template for my class(wich is called CreditCard), the data template creates a button and writes some content on it.
in the code behind i am using entity framework and linq to create a list of CreditCard, wich returns from my SQL query.
now i am trying to bind the stackPanel to that list, in order to show the buttons in the stackpanel, i have searched the web and found that i need to use ObservableCollection<T> but i have found no explenation for it.
can you help me with binding stackPanel's childern to a list of items